# Why create a reference variable of one type but assign it to another type?

Tags: java, oop

So, in one of the Java tutorials I was watching, I came across this line of code:

```
Animal mutt = new Dog();
```

Where `Dog` extends `Animal`. This line works, creating a type Animal variable referring to a Dog instance. But I wonder, can't we do this instead?

```
Dog mutt = new Dog();
```

Thanks, I hope you can shed light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do both. But sometimes there are situations where you need to operate on more than one type. I explain it easier with an example.

```
public void wash(Animal animal) { /* Happy Washing */ }
```

If you only can wash a dog but not a cat, then you can use the dog directly. But when you also can wash cats, then you should use Animal instead.

This is called liskov substitution principle [1] and is part of the SOLID Idom [2].

- [1] [What is an example of the Liskov Substitution Principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle)
- [2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID